# Set stretched background image for sizer wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython

i am wondering how to put a stretched background image in a sizer with wxpython.

I am looking at this tutorial:
http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-putting-a-background-image-on-a-panel/

but the image does not resize.

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM)
        self.frame = parent

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        for num in range(4):
            label = "Button %s" % num
            btn = wx.Button(self, label=label)
            sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        hSizer.Add((1,1), 1, wx.EXPAND)
        hSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.TOP, 100)
        hSizer.Add((1,1), 0, wx.ALL, 75)
        self.SetSizer(hSizer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnEraseBackground(self, evt):
        """
        Add a picture to the background
        """
        # yanked from ColourDB.py
        dc = evt.GetDC()

        if not dc:
            dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
            rect = self.GetUpdateRegion().GetBox()
            dc.SetClippingRect(rect)
        dc.Clear()
        bmp = wx.Bitmap("Untitled.png")
        dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0)


########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(600,450))
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Center()

########################################################################
class Main(wx.App):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, redirect=False, filename=None):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect, filename)
        dlg = MainFrame()
        dlg.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Main()
    app.MainLoop()
```

That is the code, I am not sure if resizing is possible with wxpython.  So basically I just want to be able to use a picture as the background for a sizer however have the image stretched to the sizer size.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That article isn't meant to show how to stretch or resize the image. To do that, you will probably require the Python Imaging Library (PIL). Then when you resize, you can grab the new size of the frame and use that to calculate how to scale the image. See the following link to download PIL: http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/